# Making the image position same as a background image and as an element image

Tags: html, css, image

I am using the same image as a background image for a div on one page and as an image element on another page. They take up the same space on both pages, same width and height, but the image is not positioned the same. This is the background image html:

```
<div class="frontpage-bg-image-wrapper">
    <div class="header-bg-image frontpage-header-hero"></div>
    <div class="bg-overlay overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And this is its css:

```
.frontpage-header-image-div {
   height: 100%;

   .frontpage-bg-image-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 635px;
      background-size: cover;
      background: url('/wp-content/themes/sfk/assets/images/sfk-bg.png') no-repeat;
  }
}
```

And on the other page I have a an image element:

```
<div class="hero-image-wrapper">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-bg.png">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And its css:

```
.hero-image-wrapper img{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But there is the difference in the positioning of the image, I have tried with `object-fit: cover`, but it didn't help. This is the background:

[image]

And this is the image element:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could it be possible that using it as an image src on the second item is causing the difference.  Whereas on the first you are using css to set it as the background of the div.  I would try to change the img src to a div and see if that corrects the issue.  Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Can you provide us with jsfiddle url?

Comment: @PHPLover a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) would be preferred over a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think your picture is smaller than container (specially in 'height');
background-size:cover will cut external picture to fit the container, however the 'img' tag will not.

1. First way: set the container size as same ratio as the picture ([container width] : [container height] = [image width] : [image height])
2. Second way : try the img tag's css with: 100% , height:auto

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell `cover` plus `min-height` is cropping your image a little bit, probably when it's stretched beyond the native resolution of the image.

I would do what they do to create responsive video, add `padding-bottom` as a percentage that is equal to the video's aspect ratio. If your image is 400x300 then you'd add 75% padding,

`300 / 400 = 0.75 * 100 = 75%`

Doing this allows the element to fill the width of it's container with the same proportions as your image.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  margin: 3rem auto;
  width: 70%;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url( 'http://lorempixel.com/800/400/city/4/' );
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

@media ( min-width: 1120px ) {

  .bg {
    max-width: 800px;
    padding-bottom: 400px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/city/4/">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

For the `img` element we've made it responsive. Most CSS frameworks use the three properties used on `img` for their responsive image class. Note that the image will not resize beyond it's native resolution.

For the `div` to replicate the responsive styles of the `img` we needed to use a media query to prevent the image from expanding beyond it's native resolution along with updating the bottom padding. If we don't change the padding bottom when we limit the images width then you end up with a `div` that takes up a lot more space than the background image does (creating a lot of white space below it).

Answer (score -1):

Yo could try setting background-size to 'contain'

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Leff please create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) instead of a JSFiddle.